# Display laravel Pagination links twice in a page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

I have implemented a laravel pagination in one of my project where pagination is working like a charm.

I have a requirement to display a pagination links on top of the table as well as the bottom of the table.
Like this

```
{!! $entries->render() !!}
<table class="table table-responsive" id="entries-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Advisor name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @forelse($entries as $entries)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $entries->id }} </td>
            <td> {{ $entries->name }} </td>
        </tr>
    @empty
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>No record found.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! $entries->render() !!}
```

When I try to use `{!! $entries->render() !!}` one more time in the bottom of the table or anywhere in a same page, it throws me the below error.

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to undefined method
>   App\Models\Entries::render()

here is my Controller code

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {            
        $entries = Entries::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(15);

        return view('entries.index')
            ->with('entries', $entries);
    }
```

here I am dumping the varialbe `$entries` in controller using `dd($entries)` and this is what I am getting.

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#425 ▼
  #total: 215
  #lastPage: 15
  #items: Collection {#436 ▼
    #items: array:15 [▼
      0 => entries {#437 ▶}
      1 => entries {#438 ▶}
      2 => entries {#439 ▶}
      3 => entries {#440 ▶}
      4 => entries {#441 ▶}
      5 => entries {#442 ▶}
      6 => entries {#443 ▶}
      7 => entries {#444 ▶}
      8 => entries {#445 ▶}
      9 => entries {#446 ▶}
      10 => entries {#447 ▶}
      11 => entries {#448 ▶}
      12 => entries {#449 ▶}
      13 => entries {#450 ▶}
      14 => entries {#451 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 15
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "https://samplesite.com/entries/11"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▼
    "path" => "https://samplesite.com/entries/11"
    "pageName" => "page"
  ]
}
```

Check this [Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eynDGfGM0p9RA5oHqZluj8XQBkT2SXiT/view?usp=sharing) i am sharing with you for better idea

Comment: What if you tried setting the `$entries->render()` to a variable like `@php $render = $entries->render(); @endphp` and use `$render` on the places where you use `$entries->render();`

Comment: @Refilon , I have just tried that, Not working..... I feel laravel it self not allowing to use it multiple times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not give the same name in the variable on the foreach, it could result in a conflict between.errors that might occur because abigu of a variable from the eloquent results or from the results in the loop.

try refactor your code like this

```
@forelse($entries as $entrie)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $entrie->id }} </td>
        <td> {{ $entrie->name }} </td>
    </tr>
@empty
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>No record found.</p>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you'r returning the exact collection in your blade.

```
$users= User::paginate(15);

return view('entries', compact('users'));
```

and you can use already this line in your blade.

```
{!! $entries->links() !!}
```

Or

```
{!! $users->render() !!}
```

and also in your for each, change it to this

```
@forelse($entries as $entry)
     <tr>
         <td> {{ $entry->id }} </td>
         <td> {{ $entry->name }} </td>
     </tr>
@empty
```

Try to change your controller to this.

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {            
            $entries = entries::where('form_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(15);

            return view('entries.index')
                ->with('entries', $entries);
    }
```

Comment: I have edited the question and added the controller code , Please check and let me know If anything wrong... I have already tried `{!! $entries->links() !!}` and `{!! $users->render() !!}`,  both are not allowing me to use multiple times.

Comment: Stillll......Same error bro..... You please try by creating an example at your end and let me know if it works..

Comment: where is your $id came from ? It seems that you are returning a specific row only

Comment: Its of no use,, Let me update my question... Thanks for noticing..

Comment: in your controller, could you show what is inside entries variable ?

Comment: did you try to remove first your foreach and just displayed the two paginator ?

Comment: Brother, Now seem to be we are very close.. If I remove my foreach.. it works... and allow me to render the links multiple times

Comment: just copy my foreach above, and change it in your code

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding `$entries` collection with collection item in `@forelse`.

```
@forelse($entries as $entries)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $entries->id }} </td>
        <td> {{ $entries->name }} </td>
    </tr>
@empty
```

Change `$entries` to `$entry`:

```
@forelse($entries as $entry)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $entry->id }} </td>
        <td> {{ $entry->name }} </td>
    </tr>
@empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `{{ $entries->links() }}`?

**update**

in your controller can you try this

```php
    $users = User::paginate(1);
    dd($users->links(), $users->links());
```

do you have the same error?

Comment: I tried. Same Error :-(  `Call to undefined method App\Models\Entries::links()`

Comment: Bro, On Controller side it display , and You can dump same varialbe n number of times in `dd()` Thats not the solution, while I use in my view file it doesn't work thats the problem..